# Loop Through Immutable JS Record

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

I'm new to using the ImmutableJS library and I've been having some trouble figuring this out. I have an Immutable Record object called `Options`. I want to be able to loop through this Record, getting the key and value for each item in the Record. Here's what my Options model looks like:

```
export class Option extends Record ({
  height: '10px',
  width: '47px',
  title: 'foo',
  isAvailable: false
}) {
  constructor(props) {
    if (!props) {
      super();
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

I've written the following to loop through each element inside my Options Record, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
var options = new Options();
options.toSeq().map((value, key) => {
  console.log(key + ': ' + value);
});
```

I would expect that this writes each key/value pair inside my Options Immutable Record to the console window. However, it doesn't print anything and doesn't even seem to run the code within the map function at all.

Please let me know if you have any idea what is wrong here. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `toMap` instead of `toSeq`

```
var options = new Options();
options.toMap().map((value, key) => {
  console.log(key + ': ' + value);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w6h4soay/

Comment: ImmutableJS's Record does not have a toMap() function, so this doesn't work, unfortunately. https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record

Comment: @eclaire211 You should be able to create a map from a record. It works on the JSFiddle. Do you get an error in your code?

Comment: I see. I didn't realize that it inherited from Collections. And I do see now that your js fiddle does work fine. I do get an error in my code though when I do this: `Uncaught TypeError: options.toMap is not a function`. Not sure why it's not working for me.

Comment: Also, you can try `options.toSeq().toMap()`

Comment: I am unsure as to why `options.toMap()` is not working for me, but `options.toSeq().toMap()` is working great! Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the `_values`, `_keys`, and `_defaultValues` and `_iterate` properties of the Record. I think the underscore means they are private but I can't find another way of doing it!

```
class Option extends Immutable.Record({
  height: '10px',
  width: '47px',
  title: 'foo',
  isAvailable: false
}) {}

var option = new Option();

console.log(option._keys); 
//  ["height", "width", "title", "isAvailable"]

console.log(option._values.toJS()); 
//  [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]

console.log(option._defaultValues); 
// {
//   height: '10px',
//   width: '47px',
//   title: 'foo',
//   isAvailable: false
// }

// i like this one the best
option.__iterate((item, key) => console.log(key, item));
// height, 10px
// width, 47px
// title, foo
// isAvailable, false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for of`:

```js
const options = new Options();

for (const [key, value] of options) {
  console.log(`${key}:${value}`);
}
```